# get a different variable from a calculated class

Tags: java, class

I am new at Java but becoming more and more addicted.
I created these classes:

```
Car car1 = new Car();
car1.model = "Toyota";
car1.price = 1500;

Car car2 = new Car();
car2.model = "Peugeot";
car2.price = 2600;
```

I calculated the max price with

```
      int maxprice=Math.max(car1.price, car2.price);
```

Which is the Peugeot.

Now I want to print the model of the calculated price:

```
System.out.println("The most expensive car is "+ ????);
```

Here is the problem. I can't really figure out what goes here. I thought it would be `.getmodel` or something but I can't get anything to work. I thank you in advance for your help.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to find out which car object is the more expensive. It's a bit involved for just starting with Java, but I'd write a custom `Comparator<Car>` that compared the prices and use that to choose the more expensive `Car` object.

Comment: There isn't a one line solution. A `Comparator` is the best solution in most cases, or the simple solution is a loop through your list of cars checking if each one is more expensive than any of the previous ones. I won't provide the code for this :-)

Comment: "I created these classes" You mean *instances*. Very important to get your terms straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my best solution for you:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Car car1 = new Car();
        car1.setModel ( "Toyota" );
        car1.setPrice ( 1500 );

        Car car2 = new Car();
        car2.setModel ( "Peugeot" );
        car2.setPrice ( 2600 );

        int biggestPrice = Math.max ( car1.getPrice(), car2.getPrice() ) 

        String model = "";

        switch ( biggestPrice ) {
            case car1.getprice: 
                model = car1.getModel();
                break;
            case car2.getPrice: 
                model = car2.getModel();
                break;
            default: 
                assert false : "Got a number that should not be able to appear";
                System.out.println ( "ERROR!" );
                return;
        }

        System.out.println("The most expensive car is " + model); 
    }

    class Car
    {
        String model;
        int price;

        public Car () {}

        public Car ( String model, int price ) 
        {
            this.model = model;
            this.price = price; 
        }

        public void getModel ( )
        {
            return this.model;
        }

        public void setModel (String model )
        {
            this.model = model;
        }

        public void getPrice ( )
        {
            return this.price;
        }

        public void setPrice ( int price )
        {
            this.price = price;
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helped a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't directly assign the name and price of cars. Use this

```
public void setPrice(int price)
{
    this.price = price;
}
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name= name;
}
public void getPrice()
{
    return price;
}
public void getName()
{
    return name;
}
```

Also to compare prices use a Comparator